# Select a random row in case of ties in a grouped df

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I have a data frame like below

```
df <- data.frame(group_var = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
           summ_var = c("x", "y", "z", "w"),
           val = c(100, 100, 150, 200))

df
  group_var summ_var val
1         a        x 100
2         a        y 100
3         b        z 150
4         b        w 200
```

For each `group_var`, I want to select exactly one `summ_var` with minimum `val`.
I have tried the following code:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(group_var) %>% 
    filter(val == min(val)) %>% 
    ungroup()

  group_var summ_var   val
  <fct>     <fct>    <dbl>
1 a         x          100
2 a         y          100
3 b         z          150
```

which gives me multiple `summ_var` for `group_var = a`, since `val == min(val)` is `TRUE` for multiple values of `summ_var`. How do I randomly select one of the multiple values of `summ_var` for `group_var = a`?

My desired output looks like below in which a random value of `summ_var` is picked in each group in case of conflict.

```
  group_var summ_var   val
  <fct>     <fct>    <dbl>
1 a         x          100
2 b         z          150
```

This is just a reproducible example, in reality I may have more than 2 conflicting values. Therefore, looking for a generalised approach. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(group_var) %>%
 slice(which.min(rank(val, ties.method = "random")))

  group_var summ_var   val
  <fct>     <fct>    <dbl>
1 a         x          100
2 b         z          150
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 group_by(group_var) %>%
 filter(val == min(val)) %>%
 sample_frac(1) %>%
 slice(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solves my problem. Can you tell me what is the purpose of sample_frac(1) in your code? I believe it will just return all the rows, right?

df %>%
 group_by(group_var) %>%
 filter(val == min(val)) %>%
 sample_frac(1) %>%
 slice(1)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `slice` with `sample` of `row_number()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(group_var) %>%
   slice(sample(row_number()[val == min(val)], 1))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   group_var [2]
#  group_var summ_var   val
#  <fct>     <fct>    <dbl>
#1 a         x          100
#2 b         z          150
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[min(frank(val, ties.method = 'random'))], group_var]
#   group_var summ_var val
#1:         a        x 100
#2:         b        z 150
```